# Application/system hangs that cause user to have to logoff or reboot in order to continue

Tags: windows-7, printing

Windows 7 user (accounts department) doing relatively undemanding tasks such as opening/printing an rtf invoice from a network location that cause an application hang.
If the user waits a number of minutes sometimes and then kills the app in task manager and then immediately tries again/resume the system hangs again in the same way.  Only if the user logs off or reboots can the user then continue with what they were trying to do.

The hangs are intermittent, cannot be reproduced later, and can affect standard apps such as word, pdf and printing emails.

TIA

Comment: Should read(windows 7 user (accounts department)

Comment: In an attempt to get the user to capture some information using procmon I temporarily elevated a user to local admin (procmon won't run under power users).  When this user now experiences a sysyem/application hang as before the system recovers and the user doesn't need to kill the process or logoff and the system hangs are now less frequent.  Does anybody now of a way I can get the user to start procmon capture without them having elevated priveleges?

Comment: Incidentally I have been down the normal troubleshooting route and have:  refreshed profiles (local and network), logged users onto fresh machines, checked switch ports, checked for rogue old network connections and word templates etc.

Comment: Out of a team of eleven accounts users only 3 are currently affected and each of the 3 have only had the problem since moving from XP to win7.  The rest of the team do notice a system hang from time to time but the system quickly recovers (as if they were local admins which they are not).  The only differences this department has from the rest of the general users within the organisation is a departmental network drive and a networked printer that only they use.